# PHP LDAP bind intermittent issue

Tags: php, ldap, bind

I am developing an application for my company which requires the users to log in.
To automate the log in process I have tried to integrate the ldap id and the password authentication with this app. Below is the code that I have written for this integration. I have checked online and could not find any one facing this issue.

I have this code ->

```
function isAuthenticated($u,$p) {
        $ldap_host = 'my_host';
        $ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host);
        ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
        if($ldap) {
                if($bind = ldap_bind($ldap,$u,$p)) {
                    ldap_unbind($ldap);
                    return 'Authenticated';
                } else {
                        return 'Invalid Credentials';
                    }
            } else {
                    return 'Not able to connect';
                }
    }

$username = 'preventAnonymousLogin';
$password = 'preventAnonymousLogin';

if(isset($_REQUEST['uname'])) {
        $username = $_REQUEST['uname'];
    }

if(isset($_REQUEST['password'])) {
        $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
    }

$auth = isAuthenticated($username,$password);
```

This works most of the time but some time it does not and gives this error ->

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\avrs\htdocs\ldap.php on line 12
```

I have no idea why this would work some times and some times it just don't. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

This same code works intermittently. I have tried to clear the cookies and all which seems to work some time but it is not today. So, unless I know for sure what the issue is I think I will not be able to fix this issue for good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you give the full DNS name for the ldap_host, e.g. myhost.mydomain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Error you can try setting the maximum script execution time in your C:\xampp\htdocs\avrs\htdocs\ldap.php to 60 seconds or something greater than 30 seconds. From your code above it would look something like

```
function isAuthenticated($u,$p) {
        set_time_limit(60);
       // Rest of your code from above
    }
```

[set_time_limit documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these examples. The first one is a very simple LDAP / active directory login script. The second is actually built for Yii framework but is more robust in that it handles using multiple servers in case one of them is down.

[Simple LDAP / Active Directory Form](http://www.exchangecore.com/blog/how-use-ldap-active-directory-authentication-php/)

[Yii Active Directory UserIdentity](http://www.exchangecore.com/blog/yii-active-directory-useridentity-login-authentication/)